# Distinguishing 2 lines in a file read

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, subprocess

I am doing this in order to read a file

```
f = subprocess.Popen(["../../../abc/def/run_script.sh", "cat", "def/data/ex/details.json"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
out = f.stdout.readline()
```

The file's contents that is being read from above looks like this:

```
{
         "def1": {
         "val1": 31.6, "val2" : 10
         },
         "def2": {
         "9": {
          "val1": 20.1, "val2": 22
         }
         }
         }
```

How should i go about it. When there was only 1 "val1" and 1 "val2", i did a simple search with regex and saved the values. Now that there are two, I need to be careful to know which one I am dealing with.. is there an easy way out..?

```
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 338, in loads
                                                                                                                                                               return _default_decoder.decode(s)
                                                                                                                                                                                                  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 366, in decode
                                                         obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
                                                                                                            File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
                                                                                                                                                                                  obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
ValueError: Expecting object: line 1 column 3 (char 2)
```

Comment: Given that it's JSON, can you use a JSON parser in your language of choice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [the `json` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) to parse JSON.

**Python 3 code:**

```
import json
import subprocess

with subprocess.Popen(["cat", "/tmp/foo.json"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE) as f:
    j = f.stdout.read()
o = json.loads(j.decode("UTF-8"))
print(o)
print(o["def1"]["val1"])
print(o["def2"]["9"]["val1"])
```

**Output:**

```
{'def1': {'val1': 31.6, 'val2': 10}, 'def2': {'9': {'val1': 20.1, 'val2': 22}}}
31.6
20.1
```

**Edit:**

For Python 2, use this instead.

```
import json
import subprocess

f = subprocess.Popen(["cat", "/tmp/foo.json"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
j = f.stdout.read()
o = json.loads(j.decode("UTF-8"))
print o
print o["def1"]["val1"]
print o["def2"]["9"]["val1"]
```

Comment: Lutz. thanks for your response. How would I build "s"?. "out" prints the cat of the file line by line..

Comment: Isn't  `out` the string?

Comment: s = []
        for i in iter(f.stdout.readline,""):
            s.append(i) If I did this that does not seem right. I cant seem to use "json.loads()" here. then?. Yes "out" is the string line after line.

Comment: I edited my question with the error that I am seeing using your solution. Could u please see it Lutz?

Comment: I have changed my answer.

Comment: with subprocess.Popen(["../../../abc/def/run_script.sh", "cat", "def/data/ex/details.json"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE) as f:
AttributeError: __exit__

Comment: I am using Python2.7.. http://www.diveintopython3.net/files.html has a similar error and they say that the fix is Python 3.1. I cant move from this version I am using now.

Comment: I've changed my answer for Python 2.7.

Comment: o = json.loads(f.decode("UTF-8"))
AttributeError: 'Popen' object has no attribute 'decode'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65343/discussion-between-lutz-horn-and-user2921139).

Comment: Works perfectly for my Python2.7. The 3.0 solution also is correct.